# fgets() function doesn't work

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to calculate length of string and copy the string to another without using c library function, but when I use `fgets()` function to read the string from keyboard, the code not showing the actual value of length as well as the destination string. I use the `fgets()` function instead of `gets()` because the compiler says that `gets()`function is "deprecated".but when I change `sizeof(source)` in the code to an integer value suppose `50` the code works fine. Can anybody tell me what wrong with this code and why on earth the compiler say that `gets()` function is deprecated.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int len(char *source);
char *coppy(char *dest,char *source);
int main (void){
    char *source,*dest;
    source=(char *)malloc(len(source)+1);
    printf("enter string:");
    fgets(source,sizeof(source),stdin);
    if(source[len(source)-1]=='\n'){
        source[len(source)-1]='\0';
    }

    dest=(char *)malloc(len(source)+1);
    coppy(dest,source);
    printf("dest=%s\n",dest);
    printf("length source=%d\n",len(source));
    printf("length dest=%d\n",len(dest));
    return 0;
}

int len(char *source){
    int i=0;

    while(*source!='\0'){
        source++;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
} 

 char *coppy(char *dest,char *source){
    while(*source!='\0'){
        *dest=*source;
        source++;
        dest++;
    }
    *dest='\0';
    return dest;
}
```

This is the result when run that code:

> ```
> enter string:programming
> dest=pro
> length source=3
> length dest=3
> ```

Comment: Correction: `fgets()` has been working for decades. It's *your code* using `fgets` that is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Here is your first mistake:

```
source=(char *)malloc(len(source)+1)
```

You pass `source` to the function `len` before you initialized it, which is undefined behaviour. From hereon in, anything could happen.

The second mistake is your use of `fgets`:

```
fgets(source,sizeof(source),stdin);
```

The second argument to `fgets` is supposed to be how many characters are available to be written in, not `sizeof(source)`. Read the documentation for `fgets`, and `sizeof` if necessary.

Comment: i'm expecting the length of source to be the allocated memory.and what should i do to fixed the code? –

Comment: First of all you need to decide on how much memory to allocate. You don't know this before the user inputs, so it will have to be a constant. Then you can write `source = malloc( MAX_LENGTH + 1 );` . Or even better you could write `char source[MAX_LENGTH + 1];` and avoid dynamic allocation altogether.  Then you pass `MAX_LENGTH + 1` as the length to `fgets`. (`fgets` will read at most `MAX_LENGTH` input characters, and then it will always append the null terminator).

Comment: BTW, the string you read in with `fgets` will have a `\n` on the end of it if the person pressed Enter before they typed `MAX_LENGTH` characters. You can check for this and use it to tell whether they pressed Enter or not, if you care.  You may want to remove it before copying to `dest`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in how you allocate memory for `source`

`source=(char *)malloc(len(source)+1);`

What did you expect `len(source)` to be? Play computer and run through your `len` function. I'm surprised your code compiles and runs at all. Your `len` function on an uninitialized `char*` should be undefined behavior.

That is why your code fails, you are not allocating enough memory to hold your input string.

Comment: i'm expecting the length of source to be the allocated memory.and what should i do to fixed the code?

Comment: @harianja: But you use the length of source to allocate memory for source. Doesn't that seem wrong to you? Allocate something like 256 bytes or whatever is going to be big enough to hold your biggest string; that will probably be okay in this case.